# change event calling only at once how to fix this vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
<input type = "file" @change = "update" / >

methods: {
    async update(event) {
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
        console.log("Call event", event)
    }
}
```

This file option only calling at once time i have to refresh the page to check the event. how to fix this delgate process. please guide

Thanks in advance

It should call the console all the time when i invoke file option

Comment: The change event fires whenever you change the uploaded file. Are you sure you aren't uploading the same file?

Comment: Yes same file uploading sorry for late reply

Comment: In that case you should set the value on the file input to undefined/null. This would fire the change event again. In the update handle event.target.files being undefined / length 0 which skips the appending. This should make the file fire the change handler again when you reupload the same file if that is the behaviour you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

possible reason Vue may not be properly tracking the value of the input element. The v-model directive is used to bind the value of the input to a data property in Vue instance, try adding v-model to input file

```
   <input type="file" v-model="file" @change="update" />
```

Comment: i agree with adding the v-model but FYI `@change` is [shorthand](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on) for `v-on:change` so OP already has that